# usage of complex numbers in c++

Tags: c++, fftw

I have a problem using fftw (3.3).

What I do is to create a plan first:

```
int n = 100;
vector<double> f,step;
vector<complex<double> > F;
fftw_plan p;

f.resize(n);
F.resize(n);
p = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(n,&f[0], &F[0],FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

Then what I get is the error:

```
main.cpp:19:58: error: cannot convert ‘std::complex<double>*’ to ‘double (*)[2]’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘fftw_plan_s* fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(int, double*, double (*)[2], unsigned int)’
```

As far as I understood it one could use the standart complex instead of the fftw_complex and vector.

I'm sure that I miss a simple point here. So every help would be greatly appreciated.

magu_

Comment: The fftw_complex is quite different from the c++ complex types.Try the solutions [here](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-numbers.html)

Comment: Actually `std::complex<double>` is not different (memory-wise) in C++11, so you can just do a `reinterpret_cast` on the element.

Comment: Thx for the answers.
@ DOOM: I don't think this is the problem, although I will check it out. Somehow cygwin is not very happy with mutex. But I'll try to convince it.

@ filmor: Sorry for this stupid question but is it correct like this:
p = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(n,&f[0], &reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex>(F[0]),FFTW_ESTIMATE);
because now it says: main.cpp:26:75: error: invalid cast from type ‘std::complex<double>’ to type ‘double [2]’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@filmor's way worked. For completeness, the correct line of code would be:

```
 p = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(n, &f[0], reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&F[0]), FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

More generally described [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/608597-reinterpret_cast-complex-double-double).

Comment: It seems like your actual needs changed since you posted your question (you are now creating a vector of plans from a vector of inputs). You might want to ditch the _fft[0]._ from each variable so that it reads along with your original question. *just my opinion